# "Lisp error" when trying to append hash tables to a list

Tags: hash-tables

**Q**:  Is there a way to create one cache that consists of one cons cell and two hash tables?  If so, how, please.  If not, what is the best way to handle this scenario?

**Background**:

I'm working on a new feature for speedbar that creates a cache for:

**nth 0**:  a *cons cell* -- i.e., `(cons speedbar-shown-directories (buffer-string))`

**nth 1**:  a hash table [use line number to find absolute file name]

**nth 2**:  a hash table [use absolute file name to find line number].

The cache is `speedbar-full-text-cache`.  I thought it would be handy to create a list of three elements -- the regular *last open directory is saved in its entirety for ultra-fast switching* for the first element (i.e., nth 0), and then I wanted to add two hash tables.  So the thought was to create something like:

**STEP 1**:

```
(setq speedbar-full-text-cache
  (list (cons speedbar-shown-directories (buffer-string))))
```

**STEP 2**:  Try to append two hash tables.

```
(setq speedbar-full-text-cache
  (append speedbar-full-text-cache
    speedbar-line-to-node-table speedbar-node-to-line-table))
```

**RESULT**:  *Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument sequencep #s(hash-table size 97 test eql rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data . . .*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question seems too broad.  For the part of it that is specific, it seems unclear.  Is this really all you are asking for?

```
(setq speedbar-full-text-cache
      (list (cons speedbar-shown-directories (buffer-string))
            speedbar-line-to-node-table
            speedbar-node-to-line-table))
```

Please pose as specific a question as you can, as opposed to "what is the best way to handle this scenario?" (for a vague scenario).

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem -- thank you very much -- greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

`append` wants sequences and you gave it a cons cell and two hash tables, which is why you get an error. If you want to appends sequences, give it sequences : `(append (list (cons ...)) (list hashtable1 hashtable2))` will do what you expected. But now of course it's easier and more efficient to just write `(list (cons ...) hashtable1 hashtable2)` as suggested in Drew's answer.